# Variable Assignment in Makefile

Tags: variables, makefile, variable-assignment, expansion

When making the following basic makefile the behavior I am seeing makes me think I am missing something fundamental:

```
define foo
    var := $1
    $(info var_value: [$(var)] vs value: [$1])
endef

all:
    $(eval $(call foo,FIRST))
    $(eval $(call foo,SECOND))
```

The output of that makefile is the following:

```
var_value: [] vs value: [FIRST]
var_value: [FIRST] vs value: [SECOND]
make: `all' is up to date.
```

My understanding is that `var := $1` means whatever value in $1 is immediately expanded and set into var.
Therefore I would (naively) expect the content of var and the actual value to always be equal but it is not the case. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eval` expands its parameters and make expands the result before passing it to the shell. `$$` escapes the first expansion:

```
define foo
    var := $1
    $$(info var_value: [$$(var)] vs value: [$1])
endef
$(foreach n,FIRST SECOND,$(eval $(call foo,$(n))))

all:;
```

Demo:

```
$ make all
var_value: [FIRST] vs value: [FIRST]
var_value: [SECOND] vs value: [SECOND]
make: 'all' is up to date.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a question of when things are evaluated. At first the variable `var` is empty, so on the first call `foo` expands to:

```
var := FIRST
$(info var_value: [] vs value: [FIRST])
```

Make evaluates this, and gives `var` the value "FIRST".
And since `var` has the value "FIRST", the second call to `foo` expands to:

```
var := SECOND
$(info var_value: [FIRST] vs value: [SECOND])
```

Comment: A neat trick to delay expansion by using `$(foreach var,expr,body)` to assign a value. There's also `$(value var)`, although that doesn't do expansion of subexpressions.